# Display background color for new record in AngularJS E2E testing using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am writing E2E test case for "Add New User" in my angular application.  Here, I want to display background color for the newly created user(or record). This is my test case.

```
element(by.model('newrecord.firatName')).sendKeys('Juli');      
element(by.model('newrecord.lastName')).sendKeys('Robert');                     
element( by.css('[ng-click="ok()"]') ).click();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to display background color for new record?

Answer (score 2):

Protractor isn't meant to make non-userlike changes to the page, so if you want it to change the page's background color using Protractor, you should probably reconsider. But...if you decide to go through with it, you can use `browser.executeScript(statement)`, and 'statement' will be evaluated as JavaScript, as if you were running it in the console. It would be fairly simple to select the element in question and give it a CSS `background-color` attribute this way.

If what you mean is that you want to *test* an element's background color, you can use `element(selector).getAttribute('style').then(function(style) {});` and do a bit of JS string manipulation magic to get what you're looking for. That would look something like this:

```
var bgIndex = style.indexOf('#', style.indexOf('background-color:')) + 1;
var bgColor = style.substr(bgIndex, 6);
```

The above is a little too specific (e.g. it won't work if you're using `rgb()` values), but you should get the general idea.

@jsmarkus says you can also use `getCssValue('background-color')`. This should save you some string manipulation trouble.

Comment: If you want to test background-color property, use getCssValue('background-color'). It works better